# How to print the hexadecimal in a specific manner?

Tags: c, printf, hex

In the following code I stored the mac address in a **char array**.

But even when I am storing it in a char variable, while printing it's printing as follows:

```
ffffffbb

ffffffcc

ffffffdd

ffffffee

ffffffff
```

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char *mac = "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff";
        char a[6];int i;
        sscanf(mac,"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&a[4],&a[5]);
        for( i = 0; i < 6;i++)
        printf("%x\n",a[i]);
}
```

I need the output to be in the following way:

```
aa

bb

cc

dd

ee

ff
```

The current printf statement is

```
printf("%x\n",a[i]);
```

How can I get the desired output and why is the printf statement printing `ffffffaa` even though I stored the `aa` in a char array?

Comment: `printf("%hhx\n",a[i]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `%x`, which expects the argument to be `unsigned int *`, but you're just passing `char *`. This is dangerous, since `sscanf()` *will* do an `int`-sized write, possibly writing outside the space allocated to your variable.

Change the conversion specifier for the `sscanf()` to `%hhx`, which means `unsigned char`. Then change the print to match. Also, of course, make the `a` array `unsigned char`.

Also check to make sure `sscanf()` succeded:

```
unsigned char a[6];
if(sscanf(mac, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",
          a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4, a + 5) == 6)
{
   printf("daddy MAC is %02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx",
          a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to treat your `a` array as *unsigned* chars, i.e.

```
unsigned char a[6];
```

In

```
printf("%x\n",a[i]);
```

the expression `a[i]` yields a `char`. However, the standard [does not specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default) whether `char` is signed or unsigned. In your case, the compiler apparently treats it as a signed type.

Since the most significant bit is set in all the bytes of your Mac address (each by is larger than or equal to 0x80), `a[i]` is treated as a negative value so `printf` generates the hexadecimal representation of a negative value.

Comment: hm.. can you explain why that makes a difference?

Comment: @WeaselFox I just extended my answer a bit, does that help?

Comment: I *really* think this should address the `sscanf()` issue, too.

Comment: @unwind I feel your answer addresses the issues with the `sscanf` calls quite nicely, I don't think I have anything to add to that. The incorrect usage of `sscanf` is not the reason for why the expected and observed output given by the OP diverges though (you'd have the same issue if `a` was initialized like `char a[] = { 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc ... };`). So my answer focused on that.